# Applying a function to tuple element only if that type is present in tuple

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, stdtuple

The thing I am trying to achieve is as follows, together with where i am right now:

```
template <typename Fn, typename Tuple, size_t... Is>
auto apply_if_impl(Tuple t, Fn&& f, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::make_tuple(
        std::is_same_v<std::string, std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>> ? 
        f(std::get<Is>(t)) : 
        std::get<Is>(t)...
    );
}

template <typename Fn, typename ...Ts>
auto apply_if(std::tuple<Ts...> t, Fn&& f) {
    return apply_if_impl(t, f, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>());
}
```

and implement this in a way that, for example:

```
int main() {
    std::tuple<int, std::string, float> t{42, "hello", 3.14f};

    // this one should return 
    // std::tuple<int, std::size_t, float>{42, 5, 3.14f};
    apply_if(t, [](std::string s){ return s.size(); });

    // return value of this should be equal to t above since
    // there is no vector element in the given tuple
    apply_if(t, [](std::vector<int> s){ return s.size(); });
}
```

will return another `std::tuple` but an `std::tuple<int, std::size_t, float>` with elements 42 and 5 (length of `"hello"`) and 3.14. If there is no element in the given tuple that is feasible to apply the given callable, just return the given tuple without doing anything. So, a copy of given `std::tuple<int, std::string, float>`
will be returned in this latter case, or moved, whatever.

The problem I have is that compiler still sees the function being applied to other members in the tuple, in the ternary statement I have. How can I go around this? I need a compile-time ternary thing that would expand that `make_tuple` call correctly. Lastly, I need to get rid of that hardcoded `std::string` as well. I need to put in the argument type of callable there.

EDIT: Don't hesitate to use libraries like `boost::hana` if they are going to make the solution easier. Would be a nice exercise for me as well.

Comment: It should return the whole tuple unchanged if callable is applicable to none of the tuple's elements. Come to think of it, this might not be possible since it requires the function to return different types based on the input. Still, I have faith in C++ wizards. I just need a way to find out during compile time whether this callable is going to be applicable to any element or not.

Comment: Side-note: As is right now your example, the tuple created will be of type `<int, size_t, float>` as this is what `std::string::size` returns...

Comment: Edited the question to clarify.

Comment: As you can see, it is applicable to only one element on the above example since there is only one `string` element. So, I guess this is explained in the question unless I am misunderstanding you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go via another intermediate template:

```
template <bool>
class Select
{
public:
    template <typename F, typename T>
    T& operator()(F&, T& t) const
    {
        return t;
    }
};

template <>
class Select<true>
{
public:
    template <typename F, typename T>
    auto operator()(F& f, T& t) const -> decltype(f(t))
    {
        return f(t);
    }
};

template<typename Fn, typename Tuple, size_t ... Is>
auto apply_if_impl(Tuple t, Fn&& f, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple
            (
                    Select<std::is_same_v<std::string, std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>>>()
                           (f, std::get<Is>(t))...
            );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

C++17 solution:

```
template<class Fn, typename Arg>
decltype(auto) apply_if_invocable(Fn fn, Arg&& arg) {
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<Fn, Arg>)
        return fn(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
    else
        return std::forward<Arg>(arg);
}

template <typename Tuple, class Fn, size_t... Is>
auto apply_if_impl(Tuple&& t, Fn fn, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::make_tuple(apply_if_invocable(fn, std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)))...);
}

template <class Tuple, class Fn>
auto apply_if(Tuple&& t, Fn fn) {
    return apply_if_impl(std::forward<Tuple>(t), fn, 
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>>{});
}
```

and then:

```
struct Fn {
    int operator()(int v) {
        return 0;
    }

    std::size_t operator()(const std::string& v) {
        return v.length();
    }    
};

std::tuple<int, std::string, std::unique_ptr<int>> t{
    42, "hello", std::make_unique<int>(21)};
auto z = apply_if(std::move(t), Fn{});

assert(std::get<0>(z) == 0);
assert(std::get<1>(z) == 5);
assert(*std::get<2>(z) == 21);
```

Comment: The check should be `std::is_invocable_v<Fn, const Arg&>` (which could be different if e.g. there is a deleted `Arg&&` overload).  `apply_if_invocable` should return `decltype(auto)` to avoid copying.

Comment: @aschepler, updated the answer. Please take a look.